# Choosing Primary & Foreign Keys & normalizing Person, Name, DOB & Wedding tables

Tags: foreign-key, normalization, primary-key, many-to-many

I am in the conceptual design of a database, building tables and views, selecting the PKs and FKs (primary and foreign keys) and normalizing.

Unfortunately, I am constrained to use Power Pivot on Excel to build the database, so where I would like to have a composite key I have to use an extra calculated column to generate a concatenation of columns as key.

```
Person (Name, DOB, Name-DOB [concatenated PK])
Name (Name [PK], Meaning, Origin)
DOB (DOB [PK], Astrological Sign)
```

I have a many-to-many recursive relationship that points from `Person` to `Person`, to map weddings. I need a linking table:

```
Wedding (Husband name, Husband DOB, Wife Name, Wife DOB)
```

Do I need a PK for the linking tables on the many-to-many relationships? If so, which? The only one I see (other than inventing a `Serial Number` for each row) would be a concatenation of the 4 attributes in the table, because any concatenation of 2 or 3 attributes has a chance to be non-unique. (Say someone can have a 2nd wedding after their 1st spouse dies.) But isn't a concatenation of 4 attributes too long?

Do I need to normalize the linking tables on the many-to-many relationships? If so, how? 2NF (elimination of partial dependencies) and 3NF (elimination of transitive dependencies) are impossible since `Husband DOB` depends only on `Husband Name` (same for `Wife`).

What FK do I use to link `Wedding` to `Person`? Should I use the `Husband Name-Husband DOB` and `Wife Name-Wife DOB` concatenations since `Name-DOB` is the PK of `Person`? If so, do I need to keep the individual attributes (`Husband name`, `Husband DOB`, `Wife Name`, `Wife DOB`) in `Wedding` since they are not needed in the many-to-many relationship? What problems will it pose in updating information into the database via user forms if those attributes are not there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use MS SQL terms below. I made assumptions that seemed logical, so you can drop those if they do not fit your model.

I would set up the tables in the following manner:

```
Person (PersonID int PK,
    FName Varchar(50),
    LName varchar(50),
    DoB Date FK)
Name (Name varchar(50) PK,
    Meaning varchar(MAX),
    Origin int FK)
DOB (DoB date PK,
    AstrologicalSign int FK)
Wedding (WeddingID int PK,
    HusbandPersonID int FK,
    WifePersonID int FK)
Origin (OriginID int PK,
    OriginDescription varchar(50))
Astrological Sign (AstrologicalSignID int PK,
    AstrologicalSignDescription varchar(50))
```

[image: ERD]

personID, astrologicalsignID, weddingID and originID are identity fields that auto-increment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I have a few questions if you don't mind.   
1- what would be the advantage of using a PersonID or WeddingID (which are randomly allocated numbers I presume) as the PK as opposed to using a composite PK made of (FName, LName, DOB) in the hypothetical scenario where it is impossible to have 2 persons with the same name born on the same day (in my real project, a duplicate is impossible).  
2- Why do you use the Origin Table and Astrological Sign Table ? aren't they somehow one-to-one relationships ? I was told to keep the number of tables to minimum... no ?

Comment: 1. I was thinking of a real world scenario where there is the possibility of someone with the same name and DoB existing. 

Creating a key and index off of a small value is also more advantageous in larger databases. The size of the indexes that are created are directly related to the amount of data that is stored as a key. If you use all the fields as a key you are essentially doubling the size of your table because the index will be the same size. 

When queries are run against the tables the seeks or scans will also be faster because there is less data to compare.

Comment: 2. It is better to store the number 1 (AstrologicalSignID) 30 times, instead of Sagittarius. This may not be a big deal because of the size of your project but if you were to scale it to 1,000,000 entries, think about the impact of the size of the data and any indexes that you create.


The number of tables should not be of concern to you, generally speaking. You want to make sure that your table are properly normalized and that your table and index sizes are optimized.